# getting ClassCastException on passing string array in java

Tags: java, hibernate

My sudo code is,

```
getCurrentSession().createQuery(myQueryBuilder.toString()).setParameter("gender", new String[] { Gender.MALE, Gender.FEMALE });
```

while running the query at runtime i get error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.hibernate.type.StringType.toString(StringType.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.toLoggableString(NullableType.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.pretty.Printer.toString(Printer.java:76)"
```

I think passing the string array is causing problem.

Can someone please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: MALE,FEMALE are public static final string in class Gender.

Comment: Don't you need to set Gender.MALE OR Gender.FEMALE INSTEAD OF both???

Comment: What is expected to be passed to setParameter?

Comment: You are trying to compare a string to an array

Comment: You're getting an exception because you're trying to cast an array String[] to an object String.

Answer (score 2):

When you call third party libraries and you get this type of errors, you always have to wonder if you are not using the API improperly. In your case it's easy to see from the JavaDoc that the correct method is `setParameterList` instead of `setParameter` . Remember, the JavaDoc is your bible.

I am taking a copy-paste of Hibernate 3.3 Javadoc for the class Query :

```
 Query  setParameter(int position, Object val) 
          Bind a value to a JDBC-style query parameter.
 Query  setParameter(int position, Object val, Type type) 
          Bind a value to a JDBC-style query parameter.
 Query  setParameter(String name, Object val) 
          Bind a value to a named query parameter.
 Query  setParameter(String name, Object val, Type type) 
          Bind a value to a named query parameter.
 Query  setParameterList(String name, Collection vals) 
          Bind multiple values to a named query parameter.
 Query  setParameterList(String name, Collection vals, Type type) 
          Bind multiple values to a named query parameter.
 Query  setParameterList(String name, Object[] vals) 
          Bind multiple values to a named query parameter.
 Query  setParameterList(String name, Object[] vals, Type type) 
          Bind multiple values to a named query parameter.
 Query  setParameters(Object[] values, Type[] types) 
          Bind values and types to positional parameters.
```

Answer (score 0):

1、You're getting an exception because you're trying to cast an array String[] to an object String,

```
//modify
getCurrentSession().createQuery(myQueryBuilder.toString()).setParameter("gender", Gender.MALE);
or
getCurrentSession().createQuery(myQueryBuilder.toString()).setParameter("gender", Gender.FEMALE);
```